# Setup an ObjectPool Bean with JSF-2

Tags: jsf-2, portlet

I want to create a JSF-2 Portlet with multiple SessionScoped Backing Beans. I'd also like them all to share some POJOs with a common SessionScoped Bean that will serve as an Object Pool.

I have two issues troubling me:

1. I'd like to have this bean Initialized before any of the Backing Beans. Note that no xhtml page will call an object directly to the Object Pool Bean, so at least one Backing Bean will be init before the ObjectPool. Is there some way to make sure it will be init first, except that calling in in PostConstruct of every other Backing Bean ?
2. I am confused on using ManagedProperties, because I need All the Backing beans to call the Object Pool's properties, while I also need the Backing Bean to call some Client / BackingBean functions. How can I do that without creating double references ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For your first question you can [use](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/) a `f:prerenderView` in your
  login xhtml page. `@SessionScoped` beans are not created until you
  reference them from the page or create them by yourself and store in
  the context. If you link the `f:prerenderView` to some of your method
  of the bean which acts like a pool it will be initialized for the
  rest of the HttpSession. You can later inject it in your other
  `@SessionScoped` beans using `@ManagedProperty` annotation.
- About your second question, just remember you're not forced to go
  through the view beans in order to obtain session properties. Haven't
  you made the Object Pool itself a `@ManagedBean`? So access it
  directly from your page!

Comment: thanks for the tip on prerenderedView. about the 2nd question, yes the ObjectPool is a SessionScoped ManagedBean too, but as I said, i'd rather not point at it from the xhtml pages. But if that's the only way to go, I might actually do it

Comment: Accesing your ObjectPool via your view scoped bean makes sense only if that view bean executes some logic code to modify what you want to show. Otherways, it's perfectly legitimate to access that value directly from the page, without the need of a bridge in each view bean.